# Convert factors to Year-Mon Date format without NAs

Tags: r, date

### Preface

I've done research on Stack Overflow and found several similar questions. However, my situation is quite different:

```
date<-factor(c('1990-01','1991-01','1991-02','1992-01'))
```

Notice I only have Year and Month, I would like to convert `date` to date format.

### Problem

Here's what I've done according to the answers to other SO posts:

```
date<-as.Date(as.character(data), '%Y-%m')
date
```

However, I got `NA`s.

How do I solve this? (better not use other packages like `zoo`, `anytime`)

Thank you in advance! Let me know if my question is clear and worth of asking.

Comment: `as.Date(paste0(date,"-01"))`

Comment: Hi, @d.b.Thank you! That solves the problem!

Comment: The yearmon class in zoo directly handles dates with a year and month only.  `library(zoo); as.yearmon("2000-01")`.  If you search SO for *[r] yearmon* you can find lots of other examples.  Also `?yearmon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to is to use `ymd` from the `lubridate` package. It may be faster if you have a lot of rows.

Here's a million random dates with the `yyyy-mm` format you have:

```
x <- as.character(Sys.Date()-sample(40000, 1e6, TRUE))
x <- str_sub(x, 1, str_length(x)-3)
```

Time with `as.Date`.

```
system.time({
  x1 <- as.Date(paste0(x,"-01"))
})
   user  system elapsed 
   7.91    0.00    7.95
```

Compared to `ymd` from `lubridate`.

```
system.time({
  x2 <- ymd(paste0(x, '-01'))
})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.26    0.04    0.31
```

Comment: Thank you! That not only solved my problem, but also helped optimising running time for the large dataset I'm dealing with!